# How do you add a blackhole route on your network?

Tags: ip, routing

I want to test an iPad app's response to dropped packets by adding a blackhole route on our WiFi network.  I know the command is like this:

```
ip route add blackhole 208.95.32.0/24
```

However I'm not sure where to run it.  Do I need to run this command on the wireless router itself?

Comment: What kind of wireless router?  This question should have been asked on [su]

Comment: An AirPort; thanks, I didn't know about Super User.

Comment: No problem... I flagged it for migration to [su]; no need to cross-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, use an IP access-control list (ACL) on the wifi router that filters 208.95.32.0/24... alternatively put a null route for 208.95.32.0/24 on the router, if the Apple AirPort has that kind of routing capability (I'm not sure which specific model you have).

Those options are binary, they either drop all of your traffic or none of it; if you use a simulator like [WANEm](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/), then you can configure it to drop a percentage of your traffic... similar to what you might see in a flaky wifi network.  However, this is quite involved and would require some linux skills.