# How would I add a permanent blackhole route in SLES 12?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

Similar to [How do you add a blackhole route on your network?](https://superuser.com/questions/422009/how-do-you-add-a-blackhole-route-on-your-network), but I'd like to know how to make such a route permanent in SLES 12.

In YaST I can only add "normal" routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route can be added through `yast2 lan`' in "Routing" via "Add" to "Routing Table", specifying *option* `blackhole`.
Effectively it means the a line is added to `/etc/sysconfig/network/routes` or more specifically to `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifroute-`*eth0* for interface *eth0*.

The line added may look like (for `ifroute-eth0`):

```
10.0.0.1/32 - - eth0 blackhole
```

`10.0.0.1` is the IP address and `32` is the netmask, blocking the host via interface `eth0` in the example given. The minus (`-`) stands for "value not specified".

The syntax is described in manual page `ifroute(5)` and the order of fields is:

1. Destination
2. Gateway
3. Netmask (deprecated)
4. Interface
5. Options